# ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ClassConstants

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, jersey

I a trying to try out jersey for rest service. I was trying to make a basic jersey application and I got this issue which has been a headache.
Everything works fine if I add @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML). The xml object is retrieved. But whenever I change it to JSON I get the following error response:  [image]
**And this is my server logs:**

> Aug 28, 2020 1:16:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
> invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application]
> in context with path [/RestServiceTraining_war_exploded] threw
> exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.getProvider(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectCollectionsFactory.(IndirectCollectionsFactory.java:45)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ClassConstants.(ClassConstants.java:64)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.AbstractIdentityMap.getDefaultIdentityMapClass(AbstractIdentityMap.java:339)
> at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.(Project.java:109)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:230)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:186)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2532)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2521)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

**This is what I am trying todo**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;

@Path("people")
public class PersonResource
{
  public static PersonRepository repository = new PersonRepository();

  @GET
  @Path("person/{id}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Person getPerson(@PathParam("id") int id)
  {
    return new Person(5,"Mr.E",43);
  }

  @GET
  @Path("list")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Person> getPeople(){
    return repository.getPersonList();
  }

  @POST
  @Path("person")
  public void savePerson(Person person){
    repository.addPerson(person);
  }

  @PUT
  @Path("update/person")
  public void updatePerson(Person person){
    repository.updatePerson(person);
  }

  @DELETE
  @Path("{id}")
  public void deletePerson(@PathParam("id") int id){
    repository.deletePerson(id);
  }
}
```

***My Repository Class***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonRepository
{
  public static List<Person> personList;

  public PersonRepository()
  {
    personList=new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(new Person(1,"Mr.A",24));
    personList.add(new Person(2,"Mr.B",55));
    personList.add(new Person(3,"Mr.C",18));
  }

  /**
   * Add the given Person to the List
   *
   * @param person
   */
  public void addPerson(Person person){
    personList.add(person);
  }

  /**
   * Compares the id of the person object given to check if the person object exist in the list, if yes,
   * then replaces it with the given person object.
   *
   * @param person
   */
  public void updatePerson(Person person){
    for (Person p:personList)
    {
      if (p.getId()==person.getId()){
        p.setId(person.getId());
        p.setAge(person.getAge());
        p.setName(person.getName());
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Compares the id of the person object given to check if the person object exist in the list, if yes,
   * then removes it from the list
   *
   * @param id
   */
  public void deletePerson(int id){
    for (Person p:personList)
    {
      if (p.getId()==id){
        personList.remove(p);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the List of All persons
   *
   * @return List new ArrayList<Person>()
   */
  public List<Person> getPersonList(){
    return this.personList;
  }

  /**
   * Compares the id of the person object given to check if the person object exist in the list, if yes,
   * then returns the person object
   *
   * @param id
   * @return
   */
  public Person getPerson(int id){
    for (Person p:personList)
    {
      if (p.getId()==id){
        return p;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

***My POJO Class***

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person
{
  private int id;
  private String Name;
  private int age;

  public Person(int id, String name, int age)
  {
    this.id = id;
    Name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public Person()
  {
  }

  public int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return Name;
  }

  public void setName(String name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }

  public int getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age)
  {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

***My POM FILE***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestServiceTraining</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestServiceTraining</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>RestServiceTraining</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

So what Am I doing wrong Can you please help me?

Comment: Is this the complete error log?

Comment: yes this is complete error log

Comment: Try updating to newer versions of jersey-bom

Comment: I did but to no use..